# Is it possible to create an OpenSea collection using their API?

Tags: nft, opensea, external-api, php, api

I want to create a collection in OpenSea but using a `php` backend instead of using their platform.

Is it possible to do this? I have been looking at [their API documentation](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/api-overview) and I haven't been able to find what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible yet to create a collection using OpenSea's API: the only available way is to use their website.

Source: Opensea Support Team